# データサイエンス協会が出している１００本ノックの勉強方法

Tags: python

データサイエンス協会が出している１００本ノックの勉強方法教えてください。
コードを理解して、いわゆる辞書的に使う形でしょうか？
それとも、答えも見ずにすらすらかけるようになることでしょうか？

もし後者であればかなりハードル高くて...
皆さんどう勉強しているのか、使い方教えてください。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　せっかく質問してくださったところ申し訳ないのですが、このサイトでは個々人によって答えが大きく異なり多様な回答が集まるような質問形式に対応していません。正しい答えが客観的に判断でき、なるべく事実に基づいた回答ができるような Q&A のみを対象としています。このような形式のご質問については、他サイトのご利用をご検討ください。詳しくはこちらをご覧ください: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions